# Detect connected Blackberry

Tags: c#, blackberry, usb, detect, pid

I'm trying to programatically detect in C# .NET the drive letter of connected Blackberry devices for a project. So far, I've achieved this by looking inside the drive for the folder called blackberry at the root of the device, but that is a dirty and not very elegant solution.

I tried extracting the PID and VID of USB devices, but it seems that it is not going to work on every blackberry, since there are so many.

I ran out of ideas. Anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Can you not detect based on the Vendor ID alone? All blackberry devices should (in theory) use the Research In Motion Vendor ID. According to http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids these should be:

```
0fca  Research In Motion, Ltd.
    0001  Blackberry Handheld
    0004  Blackberry Handheld
    0006  Blackberry Pearl
    0008  Blackberry Pearl
    8001  Blackberry Handheld
    8004  Blackberry Handheld
    8007  Blackberry Handheld
```

I have just connected my Bold 9900, and it is indeed using a VID of 0fca, and a device ID of 8004.

I suggest using this approach, there only appear to be a handful of device ID's (or at least that linux supports). You can identify by VID to target all blackberrys, or filter by PID to target individual revisions / models as needed.